# Struts 2 url building urls with beans

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have an action defined in Struts2, which I am using to paginate results.
If I use the form to generate the search results, everything works perfectly fine but I have tried to build next page and previous page links.
I am just unsure as to how to generate the link in such a way that the populated bean is made available to the link, if you follow.
If I try to put in a param tag, as follows, I get the standard output from a toString as the url argument.

```
<s:if test="%{authors.isNextPage()}">
<span id="nextPage">
    <s:url value="authorSearch" var="nextPageURL">
        <s:param name="startPagination" value="authors.endPagination"/>
        <s:param name="authorBean" value="authorBean"/>
    </s:url>
    <a href="<s:property value="#nextPageURL"/>">Next</a>
    </span>
</s:if>
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by *populated bean is made available to the link*i believe when user click on the next page link it should fetch next result set.

Comment: The url generated by that struts url tag is: http://localhost:4080/Loeber/ie.forasfeasa.Loeber.Action.AuthorSearchAction@c9486a5 which is not very useful.
If I take out the authorBean part of the url generation, I don't get the populated bean within the action.

Comment: i am still not clear about your use-case, if you want to take help of the paging, means you want to fetch few records and when you hit next button all you need to send the offset from which you have to send next records, i am not sure what the use of `authorBean` in this

Comment: It's a form bean. If I leave it out, the search link doesn't consider the already populated form.

Comment: Sorry, to add context. I am using a form bean to tie the .properties to HTML (for labels) and the HTML fields to properties in the Action class. I followed the tutorials on oracle to learn how to do this.

I have no idea how to incorporate that bean in a link outside of the form that it encapsulates, though, which is making my "next page of results" link difficult to generate.

I am unsure how to code the link in such a way that it is aware of the extant data in that form bean.

Comment: It appears that rather than using the bean itself to generate the link, I have to manually reference each of the bean's properties in a separate param tag.
Such that instead of having `<param name="authorBean" value="authorBean"/>`, I need to have `<param name="authorBean.someProperty" value="authorBean.someProperty"/>` and wrap that param in an if statement.

Would that seem to make sense?

Comment: yes that's more appropriate and when you go for creating paging you have to work in this way and more over HTTP request response cycle work only on string (key-value pair) and its not possible to play around the object

Comment: If you still need this solved can you elaborate further and also show the action class?

Comment: The problem is that I have a bean that I am populating by a form.

In seperate tiles, I want to have pagination links. I was hoping to be able to use the form bean to auto generate the links, but it appears that's not possible.

I have tried to use the scope interceptor, but if I have two tabs open I end up with inconsistent states.

The xQuery being built, to query my eXist DB, uses the populated form elements and returns 20 of them. I was hoping that it would be possible to automate the link generation, as any time new fields are added, I would have to edit the links as well.